# Comparing every row with all other rows with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

my goal is to compare every row with all other rows to see how many rows are unique regarding their entries. I am quite new to pandas so I am at a loss. An exemplary dataframe would be as follows:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID" : [1, 2, 3], 
                   "age": [46, 48, 55],
                   "gender": ['female', 'female', 'male']},
                   index = [0, 1, 2])
```

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve].

Comment: can you add the expected output to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want to obtain exactly?

If you want to know **per column** how many unique values you have, use [`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html):

```
df.nunique()

ID        3
age       3
gender    2
dtype: int64
```

If you want to know how many unique rows (considering combinations of columns), use [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
len(df) - df[['age', 'gender']].duplicated().sum()

# or 
(~df.drop(columns='ID').duplicated()).sum()

# or
(~df[['age', 'gender']].duplicated()).sum()

3
```

Comment: Or: len(df.drop_duplicates(subset=['age', 'gender']))

Comment: @Ze'evBen-Tsvi yes, many options, I liked to work with a boolean-only Series that should be faster/memory efficient ;)